# How to allow access to logged in users email message while using Google plus sdk in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-signin

I have got Google signin integration for my application. I successfully integrated it and by default i am getting username, usermailid, , user id and user authorization token id from sdk. Next thing i want is how to retrieve messages of Logged in user inbox. I went through the following links

https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/oauth#authorization-scopes

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#replicapoolupdaterv1beta1
But still i am getting problems and confused in getting mail messages.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/messages/{messageId}/attachments/{id}

And I strongly recommend you to use Google Playground to pick the exact API you are looking for